# How to set the column text format of QTableWidget?

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qtablewidget, qtgui

I want to show some data in table form. I took `QTableWidget` for it having multiple columns. One column of it will contain *time(hh:mm format)*.

I also want user to edit any item of table but with corresponding format.

I was able to add data in `QTableWidget` but i couldn't set text format of *time* column.

This i want to achieve so that user can edit time only in *hh:mm* format.

If possible please write your answer code in python.

Comment: Are you using [QDateTimeEdit](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qdatetimeedit.html)? Just set the display format if so.

Comment: @lpapp Actually i have added `QDateTimeEdit` before this table where user sets the time and it gets added in `QTableWidget` but in this table i want to allow user to edit this *time data* but with same format of `QDateTimeEdit`

Comment: @lpapp I have to maintain a list of data in Table form. Data includes name, time, day, temperature etc. User will configure those using corresponding widgets and then on clicking a button those will get added to the Table. And he can add mutliple datas

Comment: @lpapp Both comments convey same thing. In First comment i talked of only time widget and in second comment i told you about all contents of data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want the user enter time date, I would suggest to reuse the already existing [QDateTimeEdit](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qdatetimeedit-members.html) class in the following way:

```
dateTime = QDateTimeEdit();
dateTime.setDisplayFormat("hh:mm");
dateTime.setFrame(False);
myTableWidget.setCellWidget(row, column, dateTime);
```

The user will be able to edit the "time data" this way in your table widget. Moreover, it will be also convenient due to the steps that can be applied.

If you really insist on reinventing this yourself, you can use a QLineEdit with custom validator againt the desired `hh::mm` format.

```
dateTime = QLineEdit();
dateTime.setValidator(QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$")));
myTableWidget.setCellWidget(row, column, dateTime);
```

Comment: Just to inform you that i want time in `QTW` not `date time`. By mistake i wrote QDTE in comment

Comment: First code worked fine but second one gives error:    `dateTime.setValidator(QRegExpValidator("^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$"))
TypeError: 'PySide.QtGui.QRegExpValidator' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide.QtGui.QRegExpValidator(str)`

Comment: @Patrick: Try QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("...")) as they made the QRegExp ctor explicit.